# Inherit function arguments definition in python

Tags: python, type-hinting

If I have these two functions:

```py
def foo(code:int, *args, **kwargs):
    if code == 1:
        bar(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return None

def bar(a:str, b:int, c:int=1, d:int=2):
    pass
```

I want users can see what argument can be passed to `foo`, just like if I define `foo` like:

```py
def foo(code:int, a:str, b:int, c:int=1, d:int=2):
    if code == 1:
        bar(a, b, c, d)
    else:
        return None
```

What can I do to inherit `bar`'s argument in `foo`？

`ParamSpec` is almost there but not enough for my situation, `foo` has one more argumnt: `code` than `bar`.

Comment: "can see" how? If you're asking about an IDE, you should specify the IDE. If you're asking about type hints, [`ParamSpec`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) may be able to help, though it's a fairly new feature.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, may be either of the main ide: vscode, pycharm and jupyter. But currently I think none of them can directly show the arguments without changing my code. I'll look into ParamSpec.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, I found `TypedDict` is almost what I'am looking for but arguments in `TypedDict` can not have default value, how to resolve that?